# React Image not displaying in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a countries dropdown list with their respective flags but the image is being shown in the vs code but the browser does not display it.

The code for the dropdown component is here

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Listbox, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { BsCheck } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GoTriangleDown } from "react-icons/go";
import Image from "next/image";

interface CountriesDropdownInterface {
  title?: string;
  options: any[];
  onSelect: (value: string) => void;
  className?: string;
}

**WANT TO DISPLAY THIS IMAGE**
const flagIcon = "/assets/flags/singapore.png";

export default function CountriesDropdown(props: CountriesDropdownInterface) {
  const { title, options, onSelect, className } = props;

  const [selectedItem, setSelected] = useState<string>(options[0].countryName);

  useEffect(() => {
    onSelect(selectedItem);
  }, [selectedItem]);

  return (
    <div className={`${className}`}>
      <p className="text-gray-300 text-[0.8rem]">{title}</p>
      <Listbox value={selectedItem} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-[#3a8789] rounded-lg shadow-md cursor-default focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 sm:text-sm text-[#fff]">
            <span className="flex items-center gap-2 truncate">
              {selectedItem}
            </span>
            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
              <GoTriangleDown
                className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute z-50 w-full py-1 mt-1 overflow-auto text-base bg-[#2c3650] rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-40 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm text-[#fff]">
              {options?.map((option, index) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={index}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-4 pr-4 ${
                      active ? "bg-amber-100 text-amber-900" : "text-[#fff]"
                    }`
                  }
                  value={option.countryName}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
**This is the image **
                      <Image src={flagIcon} width="20px" height="20px" />
                      <span
                        className={`truncate flex gap-2 ${
                          selected ? "font-medium" : "font-normal"
                        }`}
                      >
                        {option.countryName}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-3 text-amber-600">
                          <BsCheck className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Path for Component:
\src\components\CountriesDropdown\index.tsx

Path for Images folder:
\src\assets\flags\singapore.png

[image: This is how it is displayed in the code window]

[image: This is the path hierachy]

The actual image I want to display is option.icon in the map function but nothing works

Comment: Why you don't add the images in the public folder since you are using nextjs? so you can do `/assets/flags/singapore.png`

Comment: @S.Marx thanks!! that was the problem. I somehow missed it. Solved now